# How to read data from file in task and use it to set another setting?

Tags: sbt, json4s

We are migrating our application to [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/). We've been working with the gradle build system and are facing a couple of issues with sbt.

We use jooq for our database, which means that our build file needs to contain the database username/password (since jooq generates code by reading the db schema). Since it isn't a good idea, all the sensitive data is stored in a protected file on each host the build might potentially run on, and the build system reads from the file and then configures the system accordingly. It was pretty straightforward in gradle, but I have hit a deadend with sbt. This is what I have till now:

```scala
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods.

val jsonBuildConfig = TaskKey[JValue]("json-build-config")

jsonBuildConfig := {
   val confLines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("/etc/application.conf").mkString
   parse(confLines)
}

jooqOptions := Seq(
  "jdbc.driver"   -> "org.postgresql.Driver",
  "jdbc.url"      -> "FIXME",
  "jdbc.user"     -> "FIXME",
  "jdbc.password" -> "FIXME"
)
```

The problem is that the three configuration parameters, with `FIXME` as their current values in `jooqOptions`, need to be picked from the file.

Within `jsonBuildConfig`, I can do this:

```scala
val confLines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("/etc/application.conf").mkString
val jsonConf = parse(confLines)
(jsonConf / "stagingdb" / "url").values
```

But how do I set it in `jooqOptions` conf set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you want the `jooqOptions` value to depend on the value of `jsonBuildConfig`. There's a section about that here:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/More-About-Settings.html

Basically, you would want to use `<<=` instead of `:=` to set `jooqOptions`, e.g.

```
jooqOptions <<= jsonBuildConfig.apply { jsonConf =>
  val dbSettings = jsonConf / "stagingdb"
  val dbUrl = dbSettings / "url"
  val dbUser = ...
  ...
  Seq("jdbc.driver" -> "...", "jdbc.url" -> dbUrl, ...)
}
```

For newer versions of SBT, you can avoid the `setting.apply{...}` pattern by calling `setting.value` within a setting initializer block, e.g.

```
jooqOptions := {
  val dbSettings = jsonBuildConfig.value / "stagingdb"
  ...
}
```

I linked to the docs for SBT 0.13.5, which does support the `.value` feature. Double-check which version of SBT you are using, and open the appropriate docs page to see if it supports that feature.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I am getting this error `build.sbt:53: error: value / is not a member of org.json4s.JValue
  val dbSettings = jsonBuildConfig.value / "stagingdb"` I am using the 2nd approach you mentioned to do this. If I am not mistaken, `jsonBuildConfig` is a `TaskKey[JValue]`, so `jsonBuildConfig.value` should be a `JValue` (which from the error message looks like it is). It is weird that I am not able to use `/` on it...

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment. The operator is `\ `, not `/`. Thank you so much for your help! This totally worked.